# UIView does not get updated correctly after setting UIImage and UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have some data that I am getting from a server and then displaying in my UIViewController class. To do this, I have two classes. The UIViewController and another one named ServerCommunicator. UIViewController is the delegate for ServerCommunicator class. The serverCommunicator looks as follows:

```
  - (void)fetchServerData:(NSString *) serverAddress{

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:serverAddress];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            [self.delegate fetchingSongsFailedWithError:error];
        } else {
            [self.delegate receivedSongsJSON:data];
        }
    }];
}
```

The UIViewController allocates the serverCommunicator, sets itself as delegate and then issue the fetch request.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.songServerCommunicator = [[serverCommunicator alloc] init];
    self.songServerCommunicator.delegate = self;
    [self.songServerCommunicator fetchServerData:<some_server_ip>];

}
```

After it does that it implements the required protocol method:

```
- (void)receivedSongsJSON:(NSData *)data{
         NSLog(@"received server response");
        /* Parses the data and displays in textfield/imageview */
}
```

My problem is that when I do display the data received in the delegate method, it doesn't get reflected right away in the UI. It is very weird, sometimes it gets shown 20 seconds laters on its own, other times it takes like a minute. I am not sure whats going on. I know for a fact that the data was fetched right away because the logged message gets printed way before the UIView gets updated.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: edit your code to add how you set values in the UI

Comment: Kindly let us  know your code where you set these values

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem was as JOJO, abdullah an rob pointed out below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other people have pointed out the problem, but they did not provide the solution in concrete code. This is the coded solution:

```
- (void)fetchServerData:(NSString *) serverAddress{

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:serverAddress];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
            ^void {
                if (error) {
                    [self.delegate fetchingSongsFailedWithError:error];
                } else {
                    [self.delegate receivedSongsJSON:data];
                }
            }
        ); 
    }];
}
```

You must understand how [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) works in iOS. GCD is an abstraction layer for multithreading.

The main queue, which your UI runs on, is a serial queue. That means you can't have two blocks of code running at the same time. It would be poor user experience if you were to do a long network query on the main queue, because it would prevent any UI code from running. This would make the app appear like it is frozen to the user.

To solve the freezing UI issue, iOS gives you other queues to do work without blocking up the main queue. iOS provides ways to create your own custom queues or use pre-made global concurrent queues. The queues that NSURLConnection uses is not known to us because we don't have the Cocoa source code. But what we do know is that NSURLConnection is definitely not using the main queue because UI is not frozen while it is grabbing data from a server.

Since NSURLConnection is running on a different thread than what the main queue (UI) runs on, you cannot just update UI at any random time. This is a common problem with multithreaded programs. When multiple threads access the same block of code, instructions may be interleaved and both blocks get unexpected results. One of the unexpected results that you experienced was the 20 second delay of the UI finally being updated. To prevent interleaving, you need to run all the UI code on the same thread. You do this by enqueuing your UI update code to the end of the main queue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on the main thread when you update the UI

Answer (score 0):

The method receivedSongsJSON() is called from a callback given to [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest] which I think is being called from a background thread.

Even if the method receivedSongsJSON() is declared in your UIViewController it will be executed in background thread if it is called from one.

As @robdashnash has indicated make sure you call all the UI updating code from main thread. If you are not sure how to do that please check the documentation of Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html).

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer that gave you correct information to solve it. I think @JoJo 's answer is best.